# React component not rendering and greyed out in vscode

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code, frontend

component not loading properly .Its also greyed out. The app is simple with just a single component with just a div in it.However I cant seem to import it.Never had this problem before.Maybe I am missing something idk.I am struggling with this for the last 5 hours .maybe problem with my system.plz help .

Code for counterr.js

```
import React from 'react'

function counterr () {
    return (
        <div>
            hello from counter
        </div>
    );
}

export default counterr;
```

code for app.js

```
import react from 'react';
import './App.css';
import counterr from './components/counterr'

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
    1234
     <counterr/>
    5678
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

[image: components]

counterr component

[image: counterr component]

app.js

[image: app.js]

Rendering the app doesnt load counterr component

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function component needs to be capitalized.

```
import React from "react";

function Counterr() {
  return <div>hello from counter</div>;
}

export default Counterr;
```

And the App.js:

```
import Counterr from "./components/counterr";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      1234
      <Counterr />
      5678
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

React (functional or class) components MUST start with a capital letter